A problem focusing on a random sum of terms of simple random walk.
For problem
"Let $\{S_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a simple symmetric random walk on the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}$, with $S_0 = a$. Define $T = \inf \{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : S_n = 0 \text{ or } b\}$, where ($0 \lt a \lt b$). Compute $\mathbb E\left(\sum_{k=0}^T S_k\right)$",
I tried as follows:
Let $S_{n} = a + X_{0} + X_{1} + \dots + X_{n}, n \ge 0$, $X_{0} = 0$, $X_{i} \sim \begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$, $i \ge 1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{T} S_{k} & = \sum_{k=0}^{T} \sum_{l=0}^{k} X_{l} \\
 & = \sum_{l=0}^{T} \sum_{k=l}^{T} X_{l} \\
 & = \sum_{l=0}^{T} (T - l + 1)X_{l}
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^{T} S_{k} \right] & = \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{l=0}^{T} (T - l + 1)X_{l} \right] \\
 & = \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} (T - l + 1)\cdot X_{l}\cdot 1_{\{ l \le T \}} \right] \\
 & = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[(T - l + 1)\cdot X_{l}\cdot 1_{\{ l \le T \}}] \text{ (DCT ?)}
\end{align}
$$
Now I get stuck. I don't know whether $X_{l}$ is independent with $T$, $1_{\{ l \le T \}}$, and don't know how to simplify. And I'm even not sure whether DCT can be used in the case above. Could any one tell me some hint about this question? Thanks!

I don't think your transition matrix for $\ X_i\ $ is correct.  Your equation $\ S_n=a+\sum_\limits{i=1}^nX_i\ $ implies that $\ X_n=S_n-S_{n-1}\ ,$ and since $\ S_n\ $ is a simple symmetric random walk on the integers this means that $\ X_i\ $ are independent random variables with $\ \mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{2}\ .$ Its transition matrix is therefore $\ \pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{2}}\ .$

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Hint
If $\ \mathfrak{S}_t=\sum_\limits{k=t}^TS_k\ $ and $\ e_s=\mathbb{E}\big(\mathfrak{S}_t\,\big|S_t=s\,\big)\ ,$ then $\ e_s\ $ is independent of $\ t\ $ and satisfies the recursion
$$
e_s=s+\frac{e_{s+1}+e_{s-1}}{2}\ ,\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
and boundary conditions
\begin{align}
e_0&=0\tag{2}\label{2}\\
e_b&=b\tag{3}\label{3}\ .
\end{align}
The quantity you're trying to find, $\ \mathbb{E}\left(\left.\sum_\limits{k=0}^TS_k\,\right|\,S_0=a\right)=$$\,e_a\ .$

 The general solution of the recursion \eqref{1} is given by $$\ e_s=A+Bs-\frac{s^3}{3}\ $$ for some constants $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ .$ The first boundary condition \eqref{2} gives $\ A=0\ $ and the second gives $\ B=1+\frac{b^2}{3}\ .$  Therefore,$$e_a=a+\frac{a(b^2-a^2)}{3}\ ,$$thus confirming the answer already given by van der Wolf.


If you consider this as an absorbing Markov chain with states $\{1,2,\dots,b-1,b\}$ where $b$ is that absorbing state, and $0$ is identified with state "b", then the transition probability for this chain is
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & \dots 0 & 0 & 0 &1/2\\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & \dots 0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 1/2 & 0 &1/2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 & 0 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Denote the top-left $(b-1)\times(b-1)$ submatrix as $P_0$ (i.e. we erase the last row and the last column). Then
if $M=(I-P_0)^{-1}$ then $m_{ij}$ is the average number of  visits to state $j$ starting from $i$ before absorption. But
$$
\nu(a):=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^T S_k\right]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{j=0}^b j\times \mathrm{card}\{k:\ X_k=j\}\right]=\sum_{j=0}^b j\times m_{aj}.
$$
For example, if $b=10$, then
$$
[\nu(1),\nu(2),\dots,\nu(9)]=[33, 64, 91, 112, 125, 128, 119, 96, 57]
$$
(If you are interested in $\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=0}^T S_k\right]$ then this is the above number, plus $S_0=a$).
It seems that the general formula would be
$$
\nu(a)=\frac{a(b^2 - a^2)}3.
$$
To obtain it, let $w$ be a vertical vector with entries $(1,2,\dots,b-1)$.  If $\nu$ is set to be a vertical vector as well, we get the equation
$$
\nu=(I-P_0)^{-1}w\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \nu-P_0\nu=w.
$$
This is equivalent to the system of equations
\begin{align}
\nu_1-\frac{\nu_2}2&=1\\
\nu_2-\frac{\nu_1+\nu_3}2&=2\\
\dots\\
\nu_{b-2}-\frac{\nu_{b-3}+\nu_{b-1}}2&=b-2\\
\nu_{b-1}-\frac{\nu_{b-2}}2&=b-1
\end{align}
One can check that the formula above indeed satisfies this system of difference equations.

Partial Answer:
The $X_l$ have no reason to be independent of $T$ -- for instance, if $a$ is much smaller than $b$ then an $X_l = -1$ for small $l$ would tend to mean the stopping time would be lower.
To use DCT, you'd have to dominate the partial sums by some nonnegative random variable you know to have finite expectation, and there is no such variable immediately apparent, although one probably(?) exists.
I believe that the best approach for this problem is based on the fact that $S_n$ seems to be a martingale.
